# Is there a function similar to array.split in AppleScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, applescript

So in Javascript you have the possibility to write something along the lines of this:

```js
let array = "This.should.be.an.array";
array = array.split(".");
console.log(array)

/* This,should,be,an,array */
```

Now I know that in Applescript there is:

```applescript
set theText to "This should be a list"
set theList to every word of theText
return theList

{"This", "should", "be", "a", "list"}
```

and also:

```applescript
set theText to "This
should
be
a
list"
set theList to every paragraph of theText
return theList

{"This", "should", "be", "a", "list"}
```

and also:

```applescript
set theText to "Thisshouldbealist"
set theList to every character of theText
return theList


{"T", "h", "i", "s", "s", "h", "o", "u", "l", "d", "b", "e", "a", "l", "i", "s", "t"}
```

But I don't know how to split an list where there are e.g. periods between the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing a while ago and the answer is not quite as simple. You have to use `Applescript's text item delimiters`. If you would want to split a string by periods you would have something like this:

```applescript
set array to "This.should.be.an.array"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
set array to every text item of array
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
```

Or written as a function it would look something like this:

```applescript
on split(theString, theSplitter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSplitter
    set theString to every text item of theString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theString
end split
```

Here is an approach that preserves your old Delimiters [posted by Erik on erikslab.com](https://erikslab.com/2007/08/31/applescript-how-to-split-a-string/):

```applescript
on theSplit(theString, theDelimiter)
    -- save delimiters to restore old settings
    set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    -- set delimiters to delimiter to be used
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    -- create the array
    set theArray to every text item of theString
    -- restore the old setting
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    -- return the result
    return theArray
end theSplit
```